# Connect to Oracle database using pyodbc

Tags: python, oracle

I would like to connect to an Oracle database with python through pyodbc. I have installed oracle driver and I tried the following script:

```
import pyodbc
connectString = """
                DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};
                SERVER=some_oracle_db.com:1521;
                SID=oracle_test;
                UID=user_name;
                PWD=user_pass
                """
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectString)
```

I got the following error message:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectString)

Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error\n (12560) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Why keyword `DBQ` works and `SID`/`Service Name` does not, see the section `21.4.1 Format of the Connection String` in Oracle 12c documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183/

or google `keywords for odbc oracle 12c`

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like your missing a PORT

Try this way

**NOTE:**
Depending on your Server the syntax can be different this will work for Windows without DSN using an SQL Server Driver.

```
connectString = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;PORT=1433;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
```

This is the connection, you still need a cursor and to use execute along with an SQL Statement..

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify server or hostname (or IP address  in connection string  for your database server is running.

Answer (score 0):

So close...

```
connectString = """
        DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};
        SERVER=some_oracle_db.com:1521;
        DBQ=oracle_test;
        Uid=user_name;
        Pwd=user_name
        """
```

I replaced SID with DBQ